# Serving static files from nginx with django + fastcgi debian

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi, static-files

I'm a little rusty when it comes to the new way of static file serving with django 1.3 however I'm sure it cannot be django that is at fault here.

I'm trying to run a django app with nginx + fastcgi on a cloud server with debian installed. We only have one server at the moment (while we develop) and will be looking to run multiple servers with a load balancer to make this a little simpler however I'm having trouble actually getting nginx to serve static files.

I've followed various tutorials for setting up nginx.conf to serve the files

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location /static  {
        autoindex on;
        root /static;
    }
}
```

The above is an extract from nginx.conf. Now no matter what I set root to, nginx throws a 404 not found error when trying to access `http://127.0.0.1/static/`.

The file structure is as follows:

```
/home/user/site/project
/home/user/site/static
/home/user/site/templates
```

Django settings.py has the following set up as STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/user/site/static/"
STATIC_URL  = "http://127.0.0.1/static/"
```

If anyone could point us in the right direction of where to do with this it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution found, based on Jim's answer above.

```
root /static
```

Has now been changed to:

```
root /home/user/site/static
```

However then checking the logs it seems that the path nginx was trying to locate at http://127.0.0.1/static was /home/user/site/static/static/ which is evidently incorrect.

I'm unsure if this is the correct method however i'm now pointing all static files into root (removing the need for /static in the url. so for /static/images I now just point it to http://127.0.0.1/images/.

Answer (score 3):

```
root /static
```

Shouldn't this be `/home/user/site/static` instead?

Comment: You would think so Jim, However regardless of what I've had that set as it has not worked.

Comment: What do the log files say?  What are the permissions for that directory and its parent directories?  What user is `nginx` running as?

Comment: static directory is 0755 i've changed root /static back to /home/user/site/static again and still no joy.

Comment: Looking at the logs it seems that the path is trying to be checked as /home/user/site/static/static/ oddly... yet at no point is that defined?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#root - **note**: Keep in mind that the root will still append the directory to the request so that a request for "/i/top.gif" will not look in "/spool/w3/top.gif" like might happen in an Apache-like alias configuration where the location match itself is dropped. Use the alias directive to achieve the Apache-like functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Check the difference between using '[root](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#root)' or '[alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#alias)'.
Basically in case of using 'root' the path next to 'location' (/static/) gets appended in path, while in case of 'alias' it'll be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation of the `root` directive, in contrast to Apache's alias directive, the location match is not dropped. So when you specify a location `static` the folder you define as your root must contain the `static` folder. So it's not wrong that nginx is looking for `/home/user/site/static/static` it is intentional behavior.

I would even prefer using `http://host/static/images` as your URL for serving static images. This way it follows the Django documentation [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) which suggests to use a prefix for you static files. Otherwise you have multiple folders for different static content cluttering your project and app folders.